# More easy way of using Interfaces to map YAML dynamically?

Tags: dictionary, go, yaml

I am trying to parse a yaml file dynamically (Therefore no struct).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "log"
)

func main() {   
    var out = `
a: First!
f: Second
b:
  c: 
    f: Third
`
    m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(out), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(m["b"].(map[interface{}]interface{})["c"].(map[interface{}]interface{})["f"])
}
```

Everytime I have to access a subkey, I am forced to convert map variable in question to (map[interface{}]interface{}). This is causing bit of a hassle for me as I have to iterate through the map.

Is there any easier method for parsing YAML file in Go?

Comment: I don't know this specific library, but from doing the same in JSON and XML, the easiest way is to deserialize a struct that is more strictly typed than a generic dictionary.

Comment: Strictly no struct.. Return structure is not predictable.

Comment: Can you at least assume that keys are always strings?

Comment: You can at least use `map[string]interface{}` and have less casting. But it's still not elegant.

Comment: Can I then index it someway like this.. m["b"]["c"]?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to flatten the yaml data structure into a key,value map in which keys and values are strings. Then if you need the actual type (5 being an int) you can do the conversion yourself. Example:

```
"a" = "First!"
"f" = "Second"
"b.c.f" = "Third"
"b.c.g.size" = "2"
"b.c.g.0 = "zero"
"b.c.g.1 = "one"
```

In Go:

```
func main() {
    any := map[string]interface{}{}
    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(out), &any)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    flatmap := map[string]string{}
    for k, v := range any {
        flatten(k, v, flatmap)
    }

    for k, v := range flatmap {
        fmt.Println(k, "=", v)
    }
}

func flatten(prefix string, value interface{}, flatmap map[string]string) {
    submap, ok := value.(map[interface{}]interface{})
    if ok {
        for k, v := range submap {
            flatten(prefix+"."+k.(string), v, flatmap)
        }
        return
    }
    stringlist, ok := value.([]interface{})
    if ok {
        flatten(fmt.Sprintf("%s.size", prefix), len(stringlist), flatmap)
        for i, v := range stringlist {
            flatten(fmt.Sprintf("%s.%d", prefix, i), v, flatmap)
        }
        return
    }
    flatmap[prefix] = fmt.Sprintf("%v", value)
}
```